# How to edit entries in matrix in R?

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

Given

```
counts = matrix(0, nrow=5, ncol=5)
```

in R, I'd like to be able to update the counts when I find new items that go into a particular box.  To this effect, I've tried

```
counts[3][3] = counts[3][3] + 1
```

but I get the error that "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length".  What's the correct way to perform this operation?

Comment: Try `counts[3,3] = counts[3,3] + 1`

Comment: `counts[3]` takes the value from col 1, row 3. This gets you a vector of lengths `1`. Another `[3]` on this vector looks for the 3rd value in that vector, which is `NA` (it's not there).

Comment: Thank you very much, DatamineR.  If you'd like to make a quick answer to that effect, I could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per DatamineR's suggestion, `counts[3,3] = counts[3,3] + 1` does the trick.